# Group multiple transactions in one voucher

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am making an accounting software that has 3 types of transactions (Issue, Receive, SalesReturn).
I have created a form for each of these, for the sake of simplicity lets just take into account 'Issue'. Now in the issue form the user can make transaction for one product at a time. This works fine, but when I am printing a invoice for transactions each Issue is coming out in different invoices. What I want is that when making an issue the user can tell the software that this transactions should be combined with the previous transaction and output it in the same invoice. The reason for this is, a single customer can be issued multiple products in a single transaction and it would be absurd to print different invoices for different products fro the same customer.
I thought of making multiple transactions in a single form but could'nt work my way around.

Just to make it more clear, right now my code works as such - if you buy an apple, mango and banana it will make 3 invoices. I want it to include all 3 items in a single receipt if the customer is same.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime 

# Cash Model
class Cash(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Cash', max_length=5)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Product Model

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventory')

# Customer Model

class Customer(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    secondary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    vat_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customers-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
   
# Issue Model

class Issue(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='SB', max_length=3)
    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    kt = models.FloatField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField(blank = True, default = 0)
    no_vat_amt = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)



    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 875 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return (self.quantity * self.rate - self.discount) * self.vat/100
    

    # Total amount exclusive of VAT
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate
    
    
    # Total amount inclusive of VAT
    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.amount)+' SAR'
    

# Receive Model

class Receive(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='RB', max_length=3)
    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    kt = models.FloatField(default=0)
    rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    no_vat_amt = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)


    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 875 * self.quantity , 2)

    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return self.amount * self.vat/100
    
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.amount
    
    @property
    def gross_amt(self):
        return self.amount + self.discount
    

    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.amount + self.vat_amt
    
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rec-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.amount)+' SAR'


# Sales-Retrun Model

class SalesReturn(models.Model):

    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='SRB', max_length=3)
    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    kt = models.FloatField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    discount = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField(blank = True, default = 0)
    no_vat_amt = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)


    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 875 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate * self.vat/100
    
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate

    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sr-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.amount)+' SAR'
```

**views.py (issue views)**

```
    # Issue Views

def issue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.IssueForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            issued_product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            form_product_qty = form.cleaned_data["quantity"]
            form_disc = form.cleaned_data['discount']
            form.save()
            product = Product.objects.get(name=issued_product)
            product.quantity = product.quantity - form_product_qty
            product.save()
            
            issue = Issue.objects.last()
            issue.amount = (issue.tot_amount - form_disc) + issue.vat_amt
            issue.no_vat_amt = issue.tot_amount - form_disc
            issue.save()
            return redirect('issue-detail', pk = instance.pk)
    else:
        form = forms.IssueForm()

    return render(request, 'issue/issue_form.html', context={'form':form})
    
class IssueListView(ListView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue/issue_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'issues'
    ordering = ['-date_time']

class IssueDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue/issue_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'issue'


def issue_report(request, pk):
    issue = Issue.objects.get(id = pk)

    
    a = issue.date

    x = int(a.strftime('%Y'))
    y = int(a.strftime('%m'))
    z = int(a.strftime('%d'))

    hijri = Gregorian(x,y,z).to_hijri()

    return render(request, 'issue/report.html', context={'issue':issue, 'hijri':hijri}


class IssueUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue/issue_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'form'
    fields = ['voucher','customer', 'product', 'quantity', 'kt', 'rate', 'vat', 'discount', 'note']

    def post(self, request, pk):  
        
        issue = Issue.objects.get(id = pk)
        pro = issue.product
        quant = issue.quantity

        if request.method == 'POST':
            
            form = forms.IssueForm(request.POST)
            
            if form.is_valid():

                instance = form.save()
                issued_product = form.cleaned_data['product']
                form_product_qty = form.cleaned_data["quantity"]
                form_disc = form.cleaned_data['discount']

                # product_id = form.cleaned_data["product_id"]
                form.save()

                product = Product.objects.get(name=issued_product)

                

                if pro.id == product.id:
                    x = (product.quantity + quant) - form_product_qty
                    pro.quantity = x
                    pro.save()
                
                else:
                    pro.quantity = pro.quantity + quant
                    
                    pro.save()

                    product.quantity = product.quantity - form_product_qty

                    product.save()
                    
                instance.amount = (instance.tot_amount - form_disc) + instance.vat_amt
                instance.no_vat_amt = instance.tot_amount - form_disc
                form.save()


                issue.delete()

                return redirect('issue-detail', pk = instance.pk)

        else:
            
            form = forms.IssueForm()

        return render(request, 'issue/issue_form.html', context={'form':form})


class IssueDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue/del_issue.html'
    context_object_name = 'form'
    fields = ['customer', 'product', 'quantity', 'kt', 'rate', 'vat']
    success_url = "/db/issue/history/"
    
    def post(self, request, pk):
        issue = Issue.objects.get(id = pk)
        pro = issue.product
        quant = issue.quantity
        if request.method == 'POST':

            pro.quantity = pro.quantity + quant    
            pro.save()
            issue.delete()
        
        return redirect('issue-hist')
```

**Report.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'issue/issue_report.css' %}">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="a4">
            <div class="eng">
                <h2 class="main">DINAR FACTORY FOR MANUFACTURING COMPANY</h2>
                
            </div>

            <div class="logo">
                <img src="{% static 'issue/d.jpg' %}" alt="My ">
            </div>

            <div class="ar">
                <h2 class="main">شركة مصنع دينار للتصنيع</h2>
                <h2></h2>
                <h2>CR.4030394066</h2>
                <h2>رقم المصنع C3-03</h2>
                <h2>مدينة مدن الصناعية الثانية</h2>
                <h2>جدة</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="vat_no">الرقم الضريبي: 311196440800003</div>

            <div class="box">
                <h1 class="sb">Sales Bill</h1>
                
                <h3 class="c_id">Customer ID: {{issue.customer.id}}</h3>
            
                <h3 class="c_name">Customer Name: {{issue.customer}}</h3>

                <h3 class="c_add">Customer Address: {{issue.customer.address}}</h3>

                <h3 class="c_cont">Contact: {{issue.customer.primary_contact}}</h3>

                <h3 class="vouch">Voucher: {{issue.id}}</h3>

                <h3 class="ref">Ref. No.: {{issue.voucher}}</h3>

                <h3 class="date">Date: {{issue.date_time}}</h3>

                <h3 class="hijri">Hijri: {{hijri}}</h3>
                           
            </div>

        </div>
     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```